# Can you create multiple polygons in R from a dataframe containing the vertices' coordinates?

Tags: r, coordinates, polygon, arcgis, r-sf

I have a data frame with 400 rows, each corresponding to a fishing area. Each row includes the coordinates of vertices of said fishing area, like this (NW = northwest corner, etc.):

```
> head(zones)
ID       NW.X     NW.Y       NE.X     NE.Y       SE.X     SE.Y       SW.X       SW.Y     NW.X.2 Effort Season  Method
1  1 -7,9961854 37.00222  -8,102379 37.05959 -8,1030245 37.01368 -7,9969111 36,9563306 -7,9961854     36 Winter Tremmel
2  2 -8,2268172 37.08076 -7,9773826 36.98974 -7,9778924 36.94389 -8,1248423 37,0183724 -8,2268172     12 Winter    Gill
3  3  -8,102379 37.05959 -7,9961854 37.00222 -7,9990974 36.75608 -8,1036475 36,8128815  -8,102379     42 Winter    Gill
4  4 -8,1024855 37.04711 -7,9963439 36.98973 -7,9994791 36.72262 -8,1036857 36,7794856 -8,1024855     42 Winter Tremmel
5  5 -8,3621785 37.02390 -7,9969701 36.93962 -7,9982745 36.83943 -8,3620979 36,9327666 -8,3621785     36 Winter    Gill
6  6 -8,2580358 37.06539 -7,9963439 36.98973 -7,9974956 36.90627 -8,2580358 36,9822685 -8,2580358     36 Winter    Gill
```

I want to create polygons of each individual area, and extract it as a shapefile to use in ArcGIS.
I've seen questions here asking how to create a polygon from a list of coordinates, but not of multiple polygons from coordinates stored in this way, and I'm a total beginner with the `sf` package.
I know that usually, you should only have 1 column with X and 1 column with Y, not like what I have here. I could reformat my data frame to only have 2 columns with the coordinates, but then how do I create the multiple polygons? I imagine with some sort of loop?

I think the answer to this question may help, but I don't understand it perfectly. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144728/add-polygons-to-spatialpolygons-via-loop-iteration-using-r

Comment: Please provide some sample data using `dput(head(mydata))`, so we can see what data we are dealing with. And you shpuld (probably) focus on the `sf`-package, and not on `sp`.

Comment: Hi, @Lise, welcome to SO. Please see the comment by Wimpel above.

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel. `dput(head(mydata)` returns a very long block, but I can add it if it will really help clarify what I'm working with. I'm now looking at the `sf` package, but I see the argument for `st_polygon` needs to be a list with numeric matrices with points in rows. I'm not sure I understand how I need to reformat my data for this.

Comment: your decimal operator is `.` in some columns, and `,` on other. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a first go at it. Not sure if I accidently switches X and Y, so please (visually) check output

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data -----
DT <- fread("ID       NW.X     NW.Y       NE.X     NE.Y       SE.X     SE.Y       SW.X       SW.Y     NW.X.2 Effort Season  Method
  1 -7,9961854 37.00222  -8,102379 37.05959 -8,1030245 37.01368 -7,9969111 36,9563306 -7,9961854     36 Winter Tremmel
  2 -8,2268172 37.08076 -7,9773826 36.98974 -7,9778924 36.94389 -8,1248423 37,0183724 -8,2268172     12 Winter    Gill
  3  -8,102379 37.05959 -7,9961854 37.00222 -7,9990974 36.75608 -8,1036475 36,8128815  -8,102379     42 Winter    Gill
  4 -8,1024855 37.04711 -7,9963439 36.98973 -7,9994791 36.72262 -8,1036857 36,7794856 -8,1024855     42 Winter Tremmel
  5 -8,3621785 37.02390 -7,9969701 36.93962 -7,9982745 36.83943 -8,3620979 36,9327666 -8,3621785     36 Winter    Gill
  6 -8,2580358 37.06539 -7,9963439 36.98973 -7,9974956 36.90627 -8,2580358 36,9822685 -8,2580358     36 Winter    Gill")

# Code -----
# Set decimal operator correct and convert all NW-like columns to numeric
cols <- grep("^(NW|NE|SE|SW)\\.[XY]$", names(DT), value = TRUE)
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", x))), .SDcols = cols]
#set to workable format df
my.poly <- setDF(DT) %>%
  # Melt to long, beep XY paired
  pivot_longer( cols = cols,
                names_to = c("point", ".value"),
                names_pattern = "(..)\\.(.)" ) %>%
  #!! check if X and Y are correct or should be switched!!
  sfheaders::sf_polygon( x = "X", y = "Y", polygon_id = "ID" ) %>%
  sf::st_set_crs(4326)

#visual incpection
mapview::mapview(my.poly)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure why the decimal operator changed in some columns and not in others, it must have happened when importing the csv because the orginal file is fine, but your solution fixed it. The X and Y did not need to be switched, I was able to create the feature and export it as a shapefile. Thank you so much!!